# How to upload the image into ftp location from servlet?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have a servlet to upload the image into ftp location. I am able to upload the image into my localhost. But I'm unable to upload into ftp location.

```
ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("D:\\Test.png"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect to the FTP Server using an ftp client; there is one in [apache commons-net](http://commons.apache.org/net/api/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html)